# Можно ли код telebot изменить на aiogram?

Tags: python, telebot, aiogram

Написал код на телеботе, но потом решил его переписать на aiogram. И столкнулся с проблемой замены:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
```

Можно ли вызвать те же самые функции на aiogram?
Полный код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import time

import db
import config
import functions

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

db.create_db()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):

  #настройка
  amount = 1
  desc = 'Тестовый товар'

  buy_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
  buy_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Купить за {amount}₽', callback_data=f'buy-{amount}-{desc}')
  buy_markup.add(buy_button)

  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Купить за {amount}₽', reply_markup=buy_markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
  #кнопка купить
  if call.data.startswith('buy'):

    call_data = call.data.split('-')

    url, code = db.add_trans(call_data[1], call_data[2])

    buy_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    buy_button_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Перейти', url=url)
    buy_button_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Проверить платеж', callback_data=f'check-{code}')
    buy_markup.add(buy_button_1, buy_button_2)

    bot.edit_message_text(f'Оплатите {call_data[1]}₽ по ссылке:', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=buy_markup)

  #кнопка проверить платеж
  elif call.data.startswith('check'):

    call_data = call.data.split('-')

    status = functions.check_pay(call_data[1])

    if status:

      price = db.update_trans(call_data[1])

      #обновления баланса или выдача товара

      bot.edit_message_text('Успешно оплачено!', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup='')

    else:
      pass


while True:
  try:
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0, timeout=5)
  except Exception as E:
    print(E.args)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю данный кусок кода

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
```

должен принимать любые колбеки, а уже внутри самой функции их обрабатывать.
По факту это аналог

```
@db.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)
async def answer(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    ...
# вроде можно его вообще пустым оставить будет тоже самое
@db.callback_query_handler()
async def answer(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    ...
```

Но я всё таки рекомендую заранее фильтровать эти данные. В вашем случае будет что-то вроде.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="buy")
async def answer(call: types.CallbackQuery):
  #кнопка купить
  call_data = call.data.split('-')
  url, code = db.add_trans(call_data[1], call_data[2])

  buy_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
  buy_button_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Перейти', url=url)
  buy_button_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Проверить платеж', callback_data=f'check-{code}')
  buy_markup.add(buy_button_1, buy_button_2)

  bot.edit_message_text(f'Оплатите {call_data[1]}₽ по ссылке:', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=buy_markup)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="check")
async def answer(call: types.CallbackQuery):
  call_data = call.data.split('-')

  status = functions.check_pay(call_data[1])
  if status:

  price = db.update_trans(call_data[1])

    #обновления баланса или выдача товара

    bot.edit_message_text('Успешно оплачено!', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup='')
```